# (how-to) get compiler warning about deprecated/unrecommended features/constructs for a certain c++year

Tags: c++, c++17, compiler-warnings

i'm looking for a compiler switch (or _SOME_MACRO) that will warn about or disallow features or constructs that are no longer recommended (although still allowed) for the "selected" c++year.

eg. when compiling g++ with switch -std=c++17 i would like a warning when using the <s>obsolete</s> superseded "typedef" construct.

that is, i would like to code in an "orthodox c++17" subset of c++17 ;-)

```
typedef int Sequence; // I would like a warning here
```

edit: to state my desire more clearly: i would like to program in the ideal/reformed subset of c++17 that the authors would have created, had they chosen to disregard any and all backwards compatibility. i know that this is not a strictly formal and true statement of affairs, but i trust that it may suffice to make my point.

Comment: You probably want [clang-tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-use-using.html).

Comment: But `typedef` *isn't* obsolete or deprecated. It's still very much a valid keyword to create type-aliases, even in the upcoming C++20 standard.

Comment: `typedef` is not (officially) deprecated.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's definitely obsolete. Obsolete, deprecated, and removed are not the same thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Again... obsolete != deprecated.

Comment: @Barry Maybe it's some nuance in the difference between the words "obsolete" and "deprecated" that I miss?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Deprecated means it is marked for future removal. Obsolete means it's out of date and there are better things. `typedef` is very unlikely to ever be deprecated, but it surely should not be used in new C++ code.

Comment: Unless C compatibility is no longer a goal of C++, typedef will never be obsolete. Obsolete mean it has fallen out of use which it most certainly hasn’t. Superseded != obsolete.

Comment: By the way, if your code base allows it, you can get clang-tidy to refactor/rewrite the code automatically for you. See: https://www.kdab.com/clang-tidy-part-1-modernize-source-code-using-c11c14/

Comment: @Barry how to achieve compiler warnings for ALL superseded features/constructs? the https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-use-using.html seems to refer only to "typedef"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with gcc and some macro abuse you could do this:

```
#define typedef _Pragma("GCC warning \"typedef is deprecated in my code base\"") typedef

typedef int Sequence; // I would like a warning here
```

will generate in gcc:

```
<source>:3:13: warning: typedef is deprecated in my code base
    3 |     typedef int Sequence; // I would like a warning here
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You can change that `_Pragma("GCC warning \"string\"")` into `_Pragma("message \"string\")` or really to `_Pragma("GCC error \"string\"")` to get a compilation error. You could add it as a parameter to your compilation line `-D'typedef=_Pragma("GCC warning \"I consider typedef to be deprecated\"")'`.

The C++ has `[[deprecated]]`, but it deprecates the variable, not the typedef, so it wouldn't have the proper intention. It would work on more compilers, so if your team/you agree on a convention, you could use it, as a hint that you agree not to use `typedef` in your code.

```
#define typedef [[deprecated]] typedef

typedef int Sequence; // I would like a warning here

int main() { 
    Sequence a;
}
```

will output in gcc 9.1:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:6:14: warning: 'Sequence' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    6 |     Sequence a;
      |              ^
<source>:3:13: note: declared here
    3 | typedef int Sequence; // I would like a warning here
      |             ^~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

As you may have guessed, since `typedef` is a compiler directive rather than a function or class, there is no way to redefine it the way you would a function or macro using `#undef` and then redefining.

```
#include <cstdio>
#undef printf

[[deprecated( “please don’t use printf!” )]]
int printf(const char *format, ...) {
```

Your best bet is to tie a linter like clang-tidy into your build system to preprocess the syntax. After all, you are wanting to give a warning directive to the *programmer* not to the compiler. It would be sensible to leave the compiler to compilation and not give it additional work.

Also, bear in mind `typedef` is perfectly valid C++ and has usefulness outside of type-aliasing the same way `union` is valid and has its role to play even with `std::variant` available.

Compiler developers *do* add these warnings themselves when a construct is completely obsoleted by the standards committee. `register` would be a prime example.

Comment: thanks @Cinder Biscuits, that sounds reasonable. i have edited my original question. could you tell me how to use clang-tidy to achieve my stated purpose? thx